# Error - The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. Try inserting or pasting less data

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-access

```
try
        {
            string CSVFilePathName = textBox4.Text;
            for (int i = 0; i < CSVFilePathName.Length; i++)
            {
                if (CSVFilePathName[i] == '\\')
                {
                    CSVFilePathName.Insert(i + 1, "\\");
                }
            }
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox4.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Select a File");
                }
                else
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    // your code here 
                    // string CSVFilePathName = @"'" + textBox4.Text + "'";
                    string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(CSVFilePathName);
                    string[] Fields;
                    Fields = Lines[0].Split(new char[] { ',' });
                    int Cols = Fields.GetLength(0);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    for (int i = 1; i < Lines.GetLength(0); i++)
                    {
                        Fields = Lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });
                        for (int f = 0; f < Cols; f++)
                        {
                            q = "SELECT * from questions where main_section='" + Fields[0] + "' AND secondary_section='" + Fields[1] + "' AND tert_section='" + Fields[2] + "' AND question='" + Fields[3] + "' AND difficulty='" + Fields[4] + "'";
                            OleDbCommand cmdn = new OleDbCommand(q, conn);
                            //MessageBox.Show(q);
                            object obj = cmdn.ExecuteScalar();
                            if (obj == null)
                            {
                                q = "insert into questions values('" + Fields[0] + "','" + Fields[1] + "','" + Fields[2] + "','" + Fields[3] + "' ,'" + Fields[4] + "')";
                                OleDbCommand cmdn1 = new OleDbCommand(q, conn);
                                cmdn1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                count++;
                            }
                            //MessageBox.Show(Fields[f]);
                        }

                    }
                    //  dataGridClients.DataSource = dt;
                    string msg = "Upload successful\n";
                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        msg=count.ToString()+" Questions missed due to their duplicates in the database.";
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show(msg);
                }

        }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Error is " + ex.ToString());
           throw;
       }
```

I am using c# winform to upload a csv file to my ms access db, but it is givig the error "The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. Try inserting or pasting less data." What should  do now?

Comment: Check the column setting in Access to see the max size.  Depending on version of Access the limits are different.

Comment: I am using access 2013 and datatype is Long Text

Comment: All fields are long text?

Comment: See followng : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2010-specifications-1e521481-7f9a-46f7-8ed9-ea9dff1fa854?CorrelationId=7312f895-519f-4eaa-9478-a7d51e747b5d&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010341462#__toc296343503

Comment: Welcome!  It looks like you're new asking questions.  You will get better help on Stack Overflow if you edit your question and include more relevant details.  It is most useful to include sample data when posting a question.  If sharing actual data is not practical, then at least summarize it by describing the maximum length of the text fields you are trying to insert.  Others already asked about the Access field size, but the error you got already pointed you toward inspecting the fields, so this would have been an excellent detail to include in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest specifying the table fields in the SQL like

```
INSERT INTO questions (fieldname1, fieldname2, ...) VALUES (...)
```

Use parameterized-values rather than writing the values directly in the string.  This also allows you to specify the datatype and then the ADO.Net OLE adapter will hopefully handle it appropriately and get the long text inserted with no trouble.  Go to [Read / Write BLOBs  ...](https://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_read_write_blob.html) for an example inserting BLOBS.  The concept and code example are very relevant to inserting Long Text values.  It demonstrates how to set up parameters for the query.  In your case, use `OleDbType.LongVarWChar` for the Long Text fields.